# How to hide or prevent from generating left navigation feature from an Appian Tempo form at runtime

Tags: formbuilder, appian

When I generate an Appian form, by default, a left navigation is included. How can I hide, or prevent from generating, the left navigation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent them from showing up. Try communicating with your Appian representative with this question though, there may be something they can do for you, but it is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the New Embedded interfaces Features ? i think in this case you can get rid of that left Navigation Features and even include your generated Sail Form in external Sites.